# How do I exchange names for a large amount of files in a folder?

Tags: files, rename, random

I want to randomize the names for about 350 files in a folder, but I want to have all the names that the files had originally. What I mean is I want All of the names in my folder randomized from the original names and no new names and no names lost. Is this possible?

(feel free to edit this question if I did not say my question clearly)

Comment: Can we get an example for the same ?

Comment: So given files `apple`, `orange`, `banana` you want them renamed randomly from the original set of names for example resulting in `orange`, `apple`, `banana`?

Comment: I think, he wants to give every one file the name of exactly one other file out of the other 349. Like a bijective function FILES -> FILES where it is: f(x)!=x.

Comment: You want no new names, yet you want to randomise the names? do you mean you want to list the in a non-alphabetic list? or do you want the new randomised names to be based on the original file names?

Comment: @roalma yes, that is what i was asking

Answer (score 1):

```
mkdir aux
ls | shuf > a                                # a=randomize list of files
(tail -n +2 a ; head -1 a) > b               # b=rotate a one line
paste a b > c                                # c=(name1 name2)*
gawk '{system( "mv " $1 " aux/" $2)}' c      # mv name1 -> aux/name2
mv aux/* .                                   # mv aux/name -> name
rm a b
```

keep `c` to revert if necessary. 
(Choose a better name for the auxiliar files)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea:

- Get a list of the original names. Save it.
- Save a shuffled version of the list (`sort -R`).
- Mangle the original list in a non-colliding way, e.g., by appending something to each name.
- Move the original files so that they reflect the mangled
  list (in order).
- Move the mangled files so that they reflect the shuffled
  original list.

In basic shell code, assuming no newlines in filenames, the current directory being the one targetted for shuffling, and the outside directory writable:

```
  find . -type f > ../list 
  < list sort -R > ../shuffled
  while read f; do mv "$f" "$f".tmp; done < ../list
  exec 3<../shuffled
  while read f; do read s <&3; mv "$f".tmp "$s"; done < ../list
  exec 3>&-
```

Comment: @ PSkocik Can you say the list in an easier way to do? I am fairly new to Linux, so could you say how to do each thing step by step? I think the way you're saying will work, I just do not understand how to do each thing.

Comment: Added code for the above described strategy.

Answer (score 0):

```
└-(>:) for i in `seq -w 1 10`; do echo $i > nonce-$i; done 
└-(>:) ls
nonce-01  nonce-02  nonce-03  nonce-04  nonce-05  nonce-06  nonce-07  nonce-08  nonce-09  nonce-10
└-(>:) for i in nonce*; do echo $i; cat $i; done
nonce-01
01
nonce-02
02
nonce-03
03
nonce-04
04
nonce-05
05
nonce-06
06
nonce-07
07
nonce-08
08
nonce-09
09
nonce-10
10
└-(>:) ../shuffle test
└-(>:) for i in nonce*; do echo $i; cat $i; done
nonce-01
06
nonce-02
03
nonce-03
04
nonce-04
02
nonce-05
09
nonce-06
10
nonce-07
05
nonce-08
08
nonce-09
07
nonce-10
01
```

And here is the code :

```
#!/bin/bash
[ -z $1 ] && echo 'please submit a target directory' && exit 1 
TargetDir=${1}
cd $TargetDir
Sourcearray=( * )
function checkArray
{
 for item in ${dest[@]}
  do
   [[ "$item" == "$1" ]] && return 0 # Exists in dest
 done
 return 1 # Not found
}
#let's shuffle the array randomly 

while [ "${#dest[@]}" -ne "${#Sourcearray[@]}" ]
do
     rand=$[ $RANDOM % ${#Sourcearray[@]} ] 
      checkArray "${Sourcearray[$rand]}" || dest=(${dest[@]} "${Sourcearray[$rand]}")
done

let i=0 
#let mv the source file to dest file name 
while [[ "${i}" -ne "${#dest[@]}" ]] ; do 
    mv ${Sourcearray[$i]} tmp-${dest[$i]}
    let i=$i+1
done  
# and rename to go back to the original name 
rename 's/tmp-//' *
```

Comment: Please remove your shell prompt when posting code/shell stuff. Thanks in advance !

Comment: @don_crissti im pretty new here, could you please point me to document describing writing policy ? Also feel free to edit my post like some other did on other questions.

Comment: There's no such document (that I know of) and I know I could edit your post but I don't want to. 1st, just imagine the OP is completely unfamiliar with the shell and copy-pastes the lines from your post in terminal, e.g. `└-(>:) ls`. The result is `bash: syntax error near unexpected token `>'` . 2nd, it's easier to select an entire line than part of the line, especially on some devices... and there's more but that's not the point. Just look at the other answers...

Answer (score 0):

There are, I know, far more elegant ways of solving this problem. This offering will not work for filenames containing newlines or those starting with a dot, but should be reasonably robust otherwise:

```
# Create a temporary directory for rename targets (allows for a->b but b->a)
DIR='.tmp'
mkdir -p "$DIR"

# How many files
LS=($(ls))
NLS=$((${#LS}+1))

# Rename the files pseudo-randomly
for SRC in "${LS[@]}"
do
    while :
    do
        # A poor approximation to a random selection. If you have `shuf`
        # this could be considerably simplified.
        RND=$((RANDOM % NLS))
        DST="${LS[$RND]}"
        echo "(trying RND=$RND -> DST=$DST)" >&2

        # Keep retrying until we find an unused filename
        test -n "$DST" && break
    done
    echo "$SRC -> $DST" >&2
    mv -f "$SRC" "$DIR/$DST"
    unset LS[$RND]
done

# Restore the renamed files to the now-empty directory
mv "$DIR"/* .
rmdir "$DIR"
```

If you need to handle filenames starting with a dot, move the temporary directory `$DIR` elsewhere and modify the `ls` command to include the `-A` flag. If you need to handle filenames containing newlines I would recommend you to use a different language, for example Perl or Python.

Answer (score -1):

There is no well-known command for that, but fortunately the shell interpreters can do this and similar tasks very easily. For example:

```
for i in /my/this/dir/*;do mv -vf "$i" "$i.$RANDOM";done
```

will step through the files in your `/my/this/dir` directory, and executes a `mv` (rename) command for that, which appends their name with a random number between 0 and 32767. For example, if you execute this for the `/sbin` directory, it will rename the files here so:

```
ifconfig -> ifconfig.4553
ip -> ip.12767
...
```

**DON'T DO IT IN /sbin, IT WILL KILL YOUR SYSTEM!** (But it would be very funny :-) )

But beware, if it is not what you want, it could be harder (another single-line, hehe) to make this back. So, before running this script, you can test it with prefixing the `mv` with an `echo`:

```
for i in /my/this/dir/*;do echo mv -vf "$i" "$i.$RANDOM";done
```

This second oneline script won't do anything, only it will print the `mv` commands which it would execute without the `echo`.

Comment: Even with the disclaimer not to do this in /sbin, I think it's bad practise to give an example of doing something that could break someone's system. If you don't advise the user to run the command in /sbin, why use that as an example? This is why 'foo' and 'bar', and so on, were invented.

Comment: This doesn't do what the questions asked for. The names were supposed to be permuted.

Comment: @peterh How would I do this to a certain folder? would I have to do the command cd? If so how would I go to a folder named 'example' in documents?

Comment: @Gilles Well, it seems I really misunderstood the problem a little bit. But the comment of the OP doesn't show it would be a problem for him.

Comment: @JohnHickox It seems a little bit I misunderstood your question, and thus I gave a different answer. How does it look now? Deserves it an upvote even in this form?